# Vb file exists script

Tags: vb.net

I have this script but would like to enhance it that in the absence of the file on the C: copy the one from the R: Drive. Currently on check if file is there.

Currently this script will run on multiple files in a single folder \SCRIPTS.
As I repeat the statement for each of different file name (I do know the file names) A more economic way of checking all files in the the R:\SCRIPTS and comparing to the C:\SCRIPTS copying or overwriting file would be good if anyone has a snippet that might help

```
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objLocalFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\SCRIPT\SCRIPTTEXT.txt")
dtmLocalDate = objLocalFile.DateLastModified

Set objServerFile = objFSO.GetFile("R:\SCRIPT\SCRIPTTEXT.txt")
dtmServerDate = objServerFile.DateLastModified

If dtmLocalDate < dtmServerDate Then
    objFSO.CopyFile objServerFile.Path, objLocalFile.Path, OverwriteExisting
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.IO;

Dim ServerFolder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("R:\SCRIPT")
Dim LocalFolder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\SCRIPT")

For Each ServerFile In ServerFolder.GetFiles
    If IO.File.Exists(LocalFolder.FullName & "\" & ServerFile.Name) Then
        Dim LocalFile As New IO.FileInfo(LocalFolder.FullName & "\" & ServerFile.Name)
        If ServerFile.LastWriteTime > LocalFile.LastWriteTime Then
            IO.File.Copy(ServerFile.FullName, LocalFile.FullName, True)
        End If
    Else
        IO.File.Copy(ServerFile.FullName, LocalFolder.FullName & "\" & ServerFile.Name)
    End If
Next
```